# What is the trouble with usage of single and double quotation

Tags: javascript

I used the below code to produce input in run time . Alert shows correctly but append causes mistake and meanwhile the single and double quotation will be changed.

```
   Var name1=$(a).attr ('name');
   Var idimg=name1+"z";
   Var nedi="<input type='file' name='zozo' onchange ='readURL(this , '" + idimg + "');' />";
$(nedi).appendTo ("#divv");
```

In run time its like :

```
<input type ="file" name ="zozo" onchange="readURL (this , "3z' ) ; '>
```

Comment: You probably meant `.appendTo("#div")`, not `.appendTo(#"div")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like that:

```
var name1 = $(a).attr('name');
var idimg = name1 + "z";
var nedi = "<input type='file' name='zozo' onchange ='readURL(this , \"" + idimg + "\");' />";
$(nedi).appendTo("#divv");
```

I.e. you should escape and use double quotes in `onchange` attribute.